# Javascript / jQuery onload function delete / add

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, prepend

I'm trying to do like animation with deleting a  and then adding another then delete the current one and then adding another, like a loop. I can do this with button, but like I said I want it like animation.

```
$("#div1").remove();

$("#div2").prepend("Some prepended text.");

$("#div2").remove();

$("#div3").prepend("Some prepended text.");
```

etc.

Comment: use typeIt which will provide typing animation

Comment: Do you want something like a blinking text, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideDown` and `slideUp`

```js
$("#div1").slideUp("slow");
$("#div1").slideDown("slow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Some prepended text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function. In this code It will slide up in 2000 second and after that it will slide down in fast speed

```js
$("#div").slideUp(2000 , function(){
    //its a callback function
    $("#div").slideDown("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">Some prepended text</div>
```